# Cannot access Guava in Android Studio

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, android-studio, guava

I am new to Android Studio.

I'm trying to add Guava to a module but somehow the reference is not resolved. This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.5'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.5'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.5'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
  compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.2'
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'
}

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }
}
```

As I can see in some other posts, the main mistake that was made is the missing reference to mavenCentral() at root level. This seems to be correct here, but the following import does not work:

```
import com.google.guava;
```

"Cannot resolve symbol 'guava'."

I have re-synced the IDE, which did not help. I have also tried to refresh dependencies:

```
gradlew --refresh-dependencies
```

I have then added an older version number to see if gradle recognizes the newer version, and it does show me in gradle.build that a newer version exists.

Further, all other references resolve fine.

Anybody has an idea what's missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava functions and data structures live under the com.google.common.* package (not com.google.guava, as the maven URL would suggest).

See documentation here: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html